# Heatmap3: how to remove legend and then move the plot to the center?

Tags: r, heatmap

I am using `heatmap3::heatmap` to create heatmaps. I do not need the legend, but I still want to use `heatmap3` over `stats::heatmap` because the colors in `heatmap3` are more smooth for my data. With the second line of code, I was able to remove the legend. However, the heatmap is not in the center. How can I move it back to the center of the plot? Thank you.

```
heatmap3::heatmap3(mtcars, Colv = NA, Rowv = NA)
heatmap3::heatmap3(mtcars, Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, legendfun=function() plot.new())
```

[image: heatmap with legend]
[image: heatmap without legend]

Using tidyverse, I got the following errors:

```
> library(ggplot2)
> library(tidyverse)
── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.2 ──
✔ tibble  3.1.8     ✔ dplyr   1.0.7
✔ tidyr   1.2.1     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
✔ readr   2.1.3     ✔ forcats 0.5.1
✔ purrr   0.3.4     
── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
> mtcars |>
+   rownames_to_column() %>%
+   pivot_longer(-rowname) %>%
+   ggplot(aes(factor(name, unique(name)), rowname, fill = value)) +
+   geom_tile() +
+   scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("blue4", "white", "red3")) +
+   scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
+   theme(legend.position = "none", 
+         axis.ticks = element_blank(),
+         axis.title = element_blank(),
+         text = element_text(face = 2))
Error in `vec_as_location()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• call = call
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─... %>% ...
  2. ├─ggplot2::ggplot(., aes(factor(name, unique(name)), rowname, fill = value))
  3. ├─tidyr::pivot_longer(., -rowname)
  4. └─tidyr:::pivot_longer.data.frame(., -rowname)
  5.   └─tidyr::build_longer_spec(...)
  6.     └─vctrs::vec_cbind(out, names)
  7.       └─vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
  8.         ├─vctrs::vec_cbind_frame_ptype(x = x)
  9.         └─vctrs:::vec_cbind_frame_ptype.default(x = x)
 10.           ├─x[0]
 11.           └─tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(x, 0)
 12.             └─tibble:::vectbl_as_col_location(...)
 13.               ├─tibble:::subclass_col_index_errors(...)
 14.               │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 15.               └─vctrs::vec_as_location(j, n, names, call = call)
 16.                 └─ellipsis::check_dots_empty()
 17.                   └─rlang:::action_dots(...)
 18.                     ├─base (local) try_dots(...)
 19.                     └─rlang (local) action(...)

> mtcars |> rownames_to_column()
               rowname  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1            Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2        Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3           Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4       Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5    Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6              Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
7           Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
8            Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
9             Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
10            Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
11           Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
12          Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
13          Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
14         Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
15  Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
16 Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
17   Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
18            Fiat 128 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
19         Honda Civic 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
20      Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
21       Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
22    Dodge Challenger 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
23         AMC Javelin 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
24          Camaro Z28 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
25    Pontiac Firebird 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
26           Fiat X1-9 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
27       Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
28        Lotus Europa 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
29      Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
30        Ferrari Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
31       Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
32          Volvo 142E 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

> mtcars |> rownames_to_column() %>% pivot_longer(-rowname)
Error in `vec_as_location()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• call = call
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `margins` argument:

```r
heatmap3(mtcars, Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, legendfun = plot.new, margins = c(10, 20))
```

[image]

Or, if you don't need the dendrogram, etc, recreate the plot in `ggplot`, which allows you to create a heatmap that fills all the space:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |>
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(name, unique(name)), rowname, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("blue4", "white", "red3")) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(face = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I copied your codes, but it won't run in my RStudio. Please see my updated question for errors.

Comment: @J.Z. you seem to be getting an unexpected error with `pivot_longer`, right at the start of the pipe. I can't replicate this erro on either of two PCs I have tried. Can you confirm that `mtcars |> rownames_to_column()` works OK, and that you get an error just by running `mtcars |> rownames_to_column() %>% pivot_longer(-rowname)`? In particular, check that the column produced by `rownames_to_column` is definitely `rowname`. If not, change `pivot_longer(-rowname)` to whatever the new row-name column is called.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Please see my update.

Comment: I am using an Intel Mac.

Comment: @J.Z. that's a very weird error. Have you tried reinstalling `tidyr` and restarting R?

Comment: I did. I guess this is a Mac-R issue. I will close this question and ask another one hoping to get some attention from Mac users. Thanks!